# DataGridView violation of parallelism

Tags: c#, datagridview

I organized form where I want to input information about organization. I organized my communication form with database in the following way.

dataGridView  plus textboxes (I want have a possibility input data both in the dataGridView control and textboxes)
     |
bindingSource
     |
dataset
     |
MySQL database.

When I add row all right. When modify all right, but when delete, espessiolly after adding some rows I get mistake on "Violation of parallelism: DeleteCommand has affected 0 of the expected 1 records"

```
private void bindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bindingSource2.RemoveCurrent();
    SynchronizeDataBase(indexrow);
}

private void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
                    .....
    if ((dataset.Tables[0].Rows[rowindex].RowState == DataRowState.Modified) ||
                                (dataset.Tables[0].Rows[rowindex].RowState == DataRowState.Added) ||
                                (dataset.Tables[0].Rows[rowindex].RowState == DataRowState.Detached))
    {
        SynchronizeDataBase(rowindex);

    }

    public void SynchronizeDataBase(int rowIndex)
{

    this.Validate();
    bindingSource2.EndEdit();
    dataadapter.Update(dataset.Tables[0]);
    dataset.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
}
```

Comment: I think that you need to set rowstate to deleted instead of removing item from bindingsource. Try dataset.Tables[0].Rows[indexrow].RowState = DataRowState.Deleted; instead of bindingSource2.RemoveCurrent();

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. Unfortunately it is impossible to set RowState property of the dataset.Tables[0].Rows[indexrow] object. VS2008 doesnt permit me to accomplish it. The text of mistake  is "Нарушение параллелизма: DeleteCommand затронула 0 из ожидаемых 1 записей." Unfortunately I have it still onlu in Russain. On more time Thank you for reply.